# Smartface IAB Helper is not set up

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, smartface.io

I'm using smartface ide for android and IOS development. When I try to buy in app product via "SMF.InAppPurchase.buyProduct()" function I get "IAB Helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: launchPurchaseFlow" error.

I bought Individual version of smartface and when I contact to smartface they said they won't help me until I buy Commercial version but it is $1990 and it is expensive for me. I'm working as freelance and my customer is so impatient.
I need help as soon as possible.

My Product is in Alpha test in Google Play and I added some in-app products.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app on real device for app billing because when using emulator some parameters are being null and it causes runtime errors. I think It may help you :)